# Can Zoom H4n record on the onboard mics and line inputs at the same time?

Tags: zoom-h4n

I want to use the Zoom H4n to record live DJ sets where I'm able to get a clear feed of the audio from the mixer (line inputs) and the crowd noise in the background (onboard microphone). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the H4n has the option for 4 channel recording, which uses both external inputs and the onboard mics. This will generate two separate .wav files, one for external and one for onboard, although in the H4n browser it displays it as one recording. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind giving me a quick 'how to' on this please?

Comment: MENU > REC > 4CH